# mongoose query to return most recent versions of documents grouped by single field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have these documents,

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "a"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test", 
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "b"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test"
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "c"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "a"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "b"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "d"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "d"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "e"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "e"
}

,
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "c"
}
```

How can i write mongoose query to sort these documents according to _id, group by subfolder ,and return most recent 5 groups.

expected result is

```js
group 1:
[{
    "_id" : 10,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "e"
},
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "e"
}]
,
group 2:
[{
    "_id" : 8,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "d"
}
,
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "d"
}]
,

group 3:
[{
    "_id" : 6,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "c"
}
,
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test"
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "c"
}]
,
group 4:
[{
    "_id" : 4,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "b"
}
,
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test", 
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "b"
}]
,

group 5:
[{
    "_id" : 2,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "B",
    "subfolder" : "a"
}
,
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "fId" : "test",
    "pId" : "test",
    "url" : "A",
    "subfolder" : "a"
}]
```

I tried a query

```js
model.aggregate(
   [      
     {$match : {fId : "test" ,  pId : "test"}},
     {$group : {_id : "$subfolder", recording: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }},     
     {$skip : 5*(pageNumber-1)},
     {$sort : {"_id": -1}},    
     {$limit : 5 }
   ]
  )
```

i get random 5 groups, not most recent, and also the result is not sorted according to _id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misanderstanding the use of skip and limit here. Try this :

```
model.aggregate(
   [      
     {$match : {fId : "test" ,  pId : "test"}},
     {$group : {_id : "$subfolder", recording: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }},     
     {$sort : {"recording._id": -1}},
     {$limit: 5}
   ]
  )
```

output with sample docs provided:

```
       {
    "_id" : "5",
    "recording" : [
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "A",
            "subfolder" : "5"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 10,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "B",
            "subfolder" : "5"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "4",
    "recording" : [
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "A",
            "subfolder" : "4"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "B",
            "subfolder" : "4"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "recording" : [
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "A",
            "subfolder" : "3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "B",
            "subfolder" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "recording" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "A",
            "subfolder" : "2"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "B",
            "subfolder" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "recording" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "A",
            "subfolder" : "1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "fId" : "test",
            "pId" : "test",
            "url" : "B",
            "subfolder" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Sabreena It works fine with the data you provided in the question... see the edit

Comment: It is grouping well, but i need the groups sorted according to _id of document.that is i need the most recent two documents with same subfolder name as group 1. and so on    (  _id : 10 is the recent document)

Comment: {$match : {fId : "test" ,  pId : "test"}},
     {$group : {_id : "$subfolder", recording: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }},     
     {$sort : {"recording._id": -1}},
     {$skip : 5*(pageNumber-1)},
     {$limit: 5}

Comment: thanks felix,its working perfectly fine!!! i added $skip to add pagination to my app.